# Convert wide data frame with counts to long format in R

Tags: r

I am struggling in transforming the data to long format

In R, I have the following data:

```
alcolevel <- c(0,0.5,1.5,4.0,7.0)
present <- c(48,38,5,1,0)
absent <- c(17066,14464,788,126,37)
dataset1 <- data.frame(alcolevel,present,absent)


     alcolevel present absent 
1         0      48  17066 
2       0.5      38  14464 
3       1.5       5    788   
4       4.0       1    126  
5       7.0       0     37
```

I wish to transform dataset1 into this:

```
alcolevel  Y
0          present
0          present
0          absent
0          absent
0          absent
 .            .
 .            .
 .            .
0.5        absent
0.5        present
0.5        present
0.5        present
 .            .
 .            .
 .            .
1.5        present
 .            .
 .            .
 .            .
7.0        present
7.0        present
```

so I get 48 present and 17066 absent for `alcolevel 0`. Same for other `alcolevel` categories.
After the transformation, the new long dataset is gonna be a long one.
I appreciate any help with this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to replicate, `uncount` on the 'value' column after pivoting to 'long' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dataset1 %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -alcolevel, names_to = 'Y' ) %>%
    uncount(value)  %>%
    as_tibble
# A tibble: 32,573 x 2
#   alcolevel    Y  
#       <dbl> <chr>  
# 1         0 present
# 2         0 present
# 3         0 present
# 4         0 present
# 5         0 present
# 6         0 present
# 7         0 present
# 8         0 present
# 9         0 present
#10         0 present
# … with 32,563 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!